# Who do I give Cheesers to?

Tags: not-tonight

I've got 10 units of CheesRs from Ferris and it seems like some sort of side job slinging drugs. But they're actually just sticks of cheese? Anyway, I can't figure out which club entrants would like them, and I've tried giving them to random people with yellow color on their clothing or hair, and it turns them off and gets me reprimanded by the boss every single time.

So who do I give the Cheesers to?

[image]

The diary/log says "Sell CheesRs at the festival" but is it on the same day as I received them? Or is it some other time? I don't see it marked clearly in the calendar tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give them to CheeseR Druggies. CheeseR Druggies wear yellow cheese hats that face right:

[image: right-hatted CheeseR Druggie]

The hat direction is important, as Undercover Cops wear similar, orange cheese hats that face left:

[image: left-hatted CheeseR Cop]

If you sell drugs to a Cop, it'll lower your credit score by 10.
Also note that selling *any* drug will lower your credit score by 1.

Answer (score -1):

people with cheese hats, but be careful some of them might be cops and that lowers your social score